# communicate with Ip camery use RTSP protocol in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, rtsp

I need to stream video from the Ip Camera. it's return Ip like this 
rtsp://[ip_address]/udp/av0_0
How to communicate with the Ip camera via flutter app

[example of communication with ip camera getting via sniffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdEJK.png)

Answer (score 2):

You can use VLC player 
your url similar 'rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.50:554/ch00/A2' 
first admin is username 
second admin is password 
A0 is Main Stream 
A1 sub Stream and 
A2 show as Mobile Stream 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player

Comment: please more details, with example code is better

Answer (score 0):

It's currently an open [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24960). You might find a native (iOS or Android) solution or use some C/C++ library via [dart:ffi](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop).

Comment: Yes I have read that. When I asked I hope there's a solution for this problem one year later.

Comment: There are plenty of "RTSP players" out there, would you use one via method channels? https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Comment: Im a beginner flutter programmer with no experience plugin making. I'll try but it is weird enough why someone have not done it earlier and publish on pub.dev

Comment: This official onvif repo https://github.com/rvi/ONVIFCameraAndroid use vlc player for streaming video. There is also vlc plugin for flutter https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player. Maybe it will worked

Comment: Also I need pass Digest auth before ip camera start streaming video, but how can I do it use just videoplayer. I've added screen of example of comminication in the Question

Comment: flutter_vlc_player can't play rtsp stream just checked it

Comment: You should try platform channels, it's not that complicated. It's the best option if you are targetting only Android though.

Comment: Ok. I will try, then write my solution in answer

Comment: Came across a similar requirement and I have implemented a rudimentary plugin to achieve this: https://github.com/oneeyedraven/flutter_rtsp_ffmpeg 
It would be great if you can help improve this.